# Problem reading in Arduino serial port with 5K potentiometer

Tags: arduino-uno

I have written code to see values of a 5K potentiometer from 0 to 1023. Whenever I rotate the knob, the value should change from 0 to 1023. I have connected the potentiometer to the Arduino's pin A1, but there is a problem with readings. Whenever I am rotating the potentiometer's knob, the serial port is only showing 1023. Please help.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A1);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Please show your actual wiring.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like it might be a wiring problem. Check that you have the potentiometer connected correctly. Your circuit should look something like this:

[image: single potentiometer circuit]

Comment: I have checked connections there is no problem with them . i dont have an idea why its only showing 1023 value .i interchanged the voltage and gnd then it showed 0 in serial port.

Comment: @shwetashrama: If your wiring is correct (which I doubt), then your potentiometer is broken.

Comment: is there any specification which one has to keep in mind while choosing a potentiometer like current rating etc.

Comment: @shwetashrama Not for applications like this. Try connecting a multi-meter across the terminals of the potentiometer to check the resistance, and verify that it changes as expected when you rotate the knob.

Comment: i have checked resistance and voltage both ,there is no problem with them

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the pot and take some readings. You should get some random values near zero. That would mean you're not connecting the leads right or the swinger is stuck at one end.